# Right adjoint preserving (trivial) cofibrations between cofibrant objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

Consider a right Quillen adjoint which is not a categorical left adjoint which takes (trivial resp.) cofibrations between cofibrant objects to (trivial resp.) cofibrations between cofibrant objects.

> Question: does this situation have a name ? Is it studied abstractly
>   somewhere ?

I would like to have other examples like mine to help me to separate what is a general fact from what is particular to the objects I am studying.

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes I have such examples. I am not surprised that it is rare. I wanted to be sure that indeed it is.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but there is a relatively natural example of this situation: the forgetful functor from algebraically fibrant object of a model category C to C, as in Nikolaus paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1342), see Theorem 3.2 , point 5 in the paper. (this was mentioned to me by John Bourke very recently). I don't think this has been studied very much though.

Comment: @SimonHenry Excellent ! Thanks.