# Very canonical constructions

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-list, examples

You have two categories $C_1$ and $C_2$. We call a map of the classes $\mathrm{Ob}(C_1)\rightarrow \mathrm{Ob}(C_2)$ *a construction*. Sometimes you can find a functor $C_1\rightarrow C_2$ inducing this map, then you call your construction functorical or canonical.

Let us all a construction *very canonical* if there is a functor inducing it and between any two such functors there exists a natural isomorphism. What are some examples of very canonical constructions naturally arising in mathematics?

Comment: Why the down-votes? Seems like a reasonable question to me (there even were some other questions on this site of similar flavour, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/q/56938/140765, https://mathoverflow.net/q/19644/140765)

Comment: I did not downvote or vote to close, but there is something a little strange about introducing a new definition seemingly "out of nowhere" and then asking others if it is non-vacuous.

Comment: @TimothyChow I agree, but I upvoted because this is a very canonical "out of nowhere" :).

Comment: Generally the onus is on whoever introduces a definition to give at least one example showing that the definition is interesting.  The other questions about words like 'canonical' and 'natural' were trying to understand how *other* mathematicians use the word.

Comment: Personally, I think this definition looks quite strange (and not at all "canonical", intuitively) from a categorical perspective: two functors inducing the same function on objects must in particular agree on objects; is the putative natural isomorphism between them required to also be the identity on objects?  If so, you're just asking the two functors to be equal (i.e. unique); but if not, you're asking for a family of *automorphisms* of objects, which is strange.  Also, uniqueness up to non-unique isomorphism is an unusual thing.

Comment: There are examples where these sorts of odd-looking things arise, like algebraic closures and more general Fraisse limits, or smothering functors in homotopy 2-categories, but it's not at all clear to me that this particular definition uses them in an interesting way.  I would suggest to the OP that if they have an example in mind of this definition, they include it in the question; and otherwise, they start from the examples they are interested in and try to formulate a definition that captures them, rather than starting from a possibly-vacuous definition and looking for examples.

Comment: I asked a similar question in https://mathoverflow.net/q/332597/24563 for a different notion and nobody downvoted... Of course I have examples and I did not include them in the post because I did not want to influence the intuition of readers. Maybe the OP has the same motivation ?

Comment: The identity on objects for the category of sets should be an example. Not sure it is very helpful though.

Answer (score 3):

Such constructions on the category of sets were studied by [Barkhudaryan, El Bashir, and Trnkova](https://eudml.org/doc/91671). They call them "DVO functors" (for "Defined by Values on Objects").

It appears there are a few papers citing this paper which study similar questions, as can be found by a [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=8758809280429585818&as_sdt=800005&sciodt=0,15&hl=en).